# Change accented letters in international with dead keys keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-language

I'm trying to use the English (intl. with dead keys AltGr) layout, since I have a US keyboard, but need to write italian text.

The combination of <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>accent</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> works fine, but the layout also offers the shortcut <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> that has the problem that by default outputs vowels with acute accent (á, é, etc), while most italian words use the grave accent (à, è, etc).

Is there a way to change the base layout to use grave accented letters instead?

Comment: I use the Compose key (in my case, the Right Win key) to do accents. For example é is generated by pressing Right Win (which latches) then e '

Comment: Maybe the _English (US, intl., with dead keys)_ layout would fit your needs better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` for editing, go to the *xkb_symbols "altgr-intl"* variant, and add these modified lines:

```
    key <AD03> { [     e,          E,        egrave,           Egrave ] };
    key <AC01> { [     a,          A,        agrave,           Agrave ] };
```

The change should be effective instantly. Please note that you may need to redo it if the `xkb-data` package is updated.

Comment: Is there a service that I need to restart in order to apply these changes?

Comment: Nevermind, switching layout refreshes the map

Answer (score 0):

We've tried to address this problem in the 'new' version of altgr-intl. Refer to [this](https://altgr-weur.eu/) webpage for an explanation.

Instructions on how to install this layout at the bottom of mentioned page.

Answer (score 0):

With `English (UK, intl., with dead keys)`/`English (US, intl., with dead keys)` you can use `` ` `` (to the left of `1` key) and press the letter you want to write. Result: `à è ì ò ù`

With `English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)` you can use `` AltGr + ` `` (to the left of `1` key) and press the letter you want to write. Result: `à è ì ò ù`

Tested in `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`.